# lsof getting ran by root, but not by a user and using high CPU usage

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, lsof

My server is using high CPU usage from lsof, and it appears to be ran randomly and by the root user. I'm finding this out via Newrelic information

Is it at all possible to find what is running this and stopping it?

Extra info: 
Some of the major apps I'm using and have installed:

- New Relic
- PHP
- Apache2.2
- Prosody
- Postfix
- MySQL

When I perform a  ps -feww | grep lsof it always just returns the grep command itself, it never seems to be running when I'm looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `auditd`, you can then create a rule such as

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/usr/sbin/lsof
```

Then see the `/var/log/audit.log` or use `aureport` and `ausearch` utilities.

Comment: I've never heard of auditd before, I will run this and I'll mark your answer as best if it works, thanks!